# Dependabot ignore and PR creation issue

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot, dependabot-script

I was working on integrating dependabot with my repo and all of a sudden , it stops creating a PR

```
updater | 2023/07/31 14:19:11 INFO <job_702837663> Finished job processing
updater | 2023/07/31 14:19:11 INFO Results:
updater | +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
updater | |                             Changes to Dependabot Pull Requests                              | 
updater | +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
updater | | created | docker/library/eclipse-temurin ( from 17.0.5_8-jre-alpine to 17.0.8_7-jre-alpine ) |
updater | +---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
updater | time="2023-07-31T14:19:11Z" level=info msg="task complete" container_id=job-702837663-updater exit_code=0 job_id=702837663 step=updater Footer
```

It shows created in log but couldnt find it in the PR list

Dependabot.yaml

```yaml
version: 2
updates:

package-ecosystem: "docker"
directory: "/base-images/test"
schedule:
interval: "daily"
time: "16:17"
timezone: "Europe/Berlin"
commit-message:
prefix: "[test]"
open-pull-requests-limit: 20
ignore:
dependency-name: "*"
update-types: ["version-update:semver-major"]
```

A PR to be created only for minor and patch releases